# Web-service that allows installation of many free apps in bulk

Tags: windows, installation, automation, windows-installer, bulk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One-stop-shop installer for free Windows software?](https://superuser.com/questions/69751/one-stop-shop-installer-for-free-windows-software)

I do know this site exist. I used it some time ago and forgot the address. Couldn't find it via search engine either.

Here is a brief description of what this site does:

Having a fresh system one just needs to go to this site and select what application he or she wants. It is possible to select browsers, image viewers, archivers, pdf reader, system utilities etc.

After choice is done this web-site genreates a special executable that you need to download and lunch. After that installion starts and *silently* installs all requested application.

Can anyone point me to this site?

Comment: Duplicate of [One-stop-shop installer for free Windows software?](http://superuser.com/questions/69751/one-stop-shop-installer-for-free-windows-software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for Ninite.com :)